# Cygwin setup no longer has src option

Tags: installation, cygwin

When installing cygwin, one used to have an option to install the source code.   This is no longer available in the default interface.   I've looked here to see how to get the source:

[https://x.cygwin.com/docs/cg/prog-obtaining-source.html#:~:text=If%20you%20just%20want%20to,xserver%2Fhw%2Fxwin%20directory.](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/cg/prog-obtaining-source.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20just%20want%20to,xserver%2Fhw%2Fxwin%20directory.)

However, I have had no success with any of the options.   I have not tried installing the main tree and applying the patches as that sounds like too much work.   At the moment, I am specifically interested in the rxvt source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box for selecting the SRC code is still there

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Thank you so much.   I think it used to be an option on the drop-down and not a radio box, which is why I didn't notice it.